# How to get the text of a TextView from a custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-arrayadapter, onitemclicklistener

I've done a custom `ArrayAdapter` that contains two views: an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. Then I set a ListView with this `ArrayAdapter`.

When I click on a row of the `ListView` the `onItemClick(...)` is invoked and I want to do this:

```
OnItemClickListener cl = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClubList.class);
        intent.putExtra("CountryName", ((TextView) view).getText());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Obviously, I can't do `((TextView) view).getText()` because it's a view that contains one `ImageView` and one `TextView`. How can I get access to the text of the `TextView`?

Comment: Please provide the code you use to instanciate your custom adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know if these work's

```
TextView blabla = (TextView)view.findViewById(id.blablaid);
```

and then

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClubList.class);
        intent.putExtra("CountryName", blabla.getText());
        startActivity(intent);
```